# Background frame loop matlab

Tags: matlab, loops, video-processing

Im trying to make a loop for doing the same operation to a lot of .mov files in matlab. The code i have right now looks like this:

```
close all
clear all 
clc

movFiles = dir('*.mov');
numFiles = length(movFiles);
mydata = cell(1,numFiles);

% mydata = zeros(numFiles);
for k = 1:numFiles
    mydata{1,k} = VideoReader(movFiles(k).name);
end


for k=1:numFiles
bk_downsample = 5; %The downsample factor for frame averaging 
%disp('Opening video...') %lower number =longer computation time
vob = mydata; 
frame = vob.read(inf); %Reads to end = vob knows the number of frames
vidHeight = vob.Height;
vidWidth = vob.Width;
nFrames = vob.NumberOfFrames;

%% First-iteration background frame
background_frame = double(frame*0);
disp('Calculating background...')
for k = 1:bk_downsample:nFrames
    background_frame = background_frame + double(read(vob, k));
    disp(k/(nFrames)*100)
end

%background_frame = uint8(bk_downsample*background_frame/(nFrames));
background_frame = bk_downsample*background_frame/(nFrames);

%imshow(background_frame)

%% Second-iteration background frame
%This section re-calculates the background frame while attempting to
%minimize the effect of moving objects in the calculation

background_frame2 = double(frame*0);
pixel_sample_density = im2bw(double(frame*0));
diff_frame = double(frame*0);
stream_frame = diff_frame(:,:,1);
bk_downsample = 10;

figure
hold on
for k = 1:bk_downsample:nFrames
    diff_frame = imabsdiff(double(read(vob, k)), background_frame);
    diff_frame = 1-im2bw(uint8(diff_frame),.25);
    pixel_sample_density = pixel_sample_density + diff_frame;
    stream_frame = stream_frame + (1-diff_frame)/(nFrames/bk_downsample);
    nonmoving = double(read(vob, k));
    nonmoving(:,:,1) = nonmoving(:,:,1).*diff_frame;
    nonmoving(:,:,2) = nonmoving(:,:,2).*diff_frame;
    nonmoving(:,:,3) = nonmoving(:,:,3).*diff_frame;
    background_frame2 = background_frame2 + nonmoving;
    %pause
    disp(k/(nFrames)*100)
end

background_frame2(:,:,1) = background_frame2(:,:,1)./pixel_sample_density;
background_frame2(:,:,2) = background_frame2(:,:,2)./pixel_sample_density;
background_frame2(:,:,3) = background_frame2(:,:,3)./pixel_sample_density;


imshow(uint8(background_frame2))
%imshow(stream_frame)
   filename = ['Ring_' num2str(k) '_background_' num2str(img) '.jpg'];
imwrite((uint8(background_frame2)),filename)
end
```

I know that the error starts with vob=mydata; but im not sure how to correct it, hope that someone is able to help me since it would save me a lot of time in my data-analysis. 
Have a great day! :)

Comment: What is the error? Do you get any error messages?

Comment: Struct contents reference from a non-struct array object.

Error in ExtractBackground (line 19)
frame = vob.read(inf); %Reads to end = vob knows the number of frames

Comment: Where does `VideoReader` come from?

Comment: @MatthiasW. [It's a MATLAB function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/videoreader.html)...

Comment: @excaza: ah thanks, I see. Thought my MATLAB was not having it. Had not paid enough attention. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't make much sense... You're creating a cell array:

```
mydata = cell(1,numFiles);
%// . . .
        mydata{1,k} = . . .
```

but however you try to access it like a structure:

```
vob = mydata; 
frame = vob.read(inf);
```

If I'd guess, then your error stems from you forgetting to index in the cell array, i.e.:

```
vob = mydata{k};
```

Other programming oddity I noticed in your code is the fact you're using the same looping variable `k`, in two nested `for` lops, the outer one being on `k=1:numFiles` and the inner ones being on `k=1:bk_downsample:nFrames`; don't do that unless you're trying to drive yourself crazy while figuring out why your for loop executes only once. Name them `k1` for the outer loop and `k2` for the inner loops and you'll be happier.

Comment: Minor nit, he's trying to invoke the `read` method of the `VideoReader` object he creates, not access it like a structure. Though I'm pretty sure `VideoReader` doesn't have a `read` method. Perhaps `readFrame`...

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert in video processing, but for me it looks like your line should be:

```
vob=mydata{1,k};
```

That's why that error shows up, because you are treating a cell of structs as if it was a single struct.